# How to configure apache for flask and php on the same server

Tags: python, php, apache, mod-wsgi

The server that I've been upgrading/updating has pages using php and python. I've rewritten the python based pages using the Flask framework and apache is configured using wsgi:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName my_fake_site
    ...
    AliasMatch ^\/((?:flask_dir1|flask_dir2).*)\.((css|php|png)$((?:\?.*)?)) /var/www/html/app/$1.$2
    AliasMatch ^\/(.*)\.(css|html|php|png) /var/www/html/$1.$2

    WSGIDaemonProcess main_proc processes=8 python-home=/var/www/html/venv
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/wsgi.py
    <Directory /var/www/html/>
        WSGIProcessGroup main_proc
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL} 
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    SSLEngine on
    ...
</VirtualHost>

WSGIPythonPath /var/www/html
WSGIPythonHome /var/www/html/venv
```

On the old server, urls pointing to directories default to `index.php` using the `DirectoryIndex` option (set in another conf file). On the new server, I get an "internal server error" message and a 500 response code in the error log.

So ultimately the question is, how do I configure apache to serve both pages handled by php and pages handled by python? (Note: there are a few pages handled by php in the flask directories)

**EDIT:** I added another `AliasMatch` line that *seems* to do what I want. I was also able to remove 'php' from the second `AliasMatch` line:

```
AliasMatch ^\/((?:flask_dir1|flask_dir2).*)\.((css|php|png)$((?:\?.*)?)) /var/www/html/app/$1.$2
AliasMatch ^\/(.*)\.(css|html|png) /var/www/html/$1.$2
AliasMatch ^\/((?:php_dir1|php_dir2).*) /var/www/html/$1
```

Comment: The directory directive needs a path to a directory, not a file.

Comment: I modified the ```Directory``` line so that it just points to ```/var/www/html/```. It doesn't seem like it changed anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my edit, the `AliasMatch` directive worked. From [the documentation](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/master/user-guides/configuration-guidelines.html?highlight=aliasmatch#hosting-of-static-files), this allows Apache to host static files, which I guess also includes php files.